# Sqlite using dbCommand returning "unknown error insufficient parameters supplied to the command"

Tags: vb.net, system.data.sqlite

This works in SqliteStudio with values for parameters, but it does not work with dbCommand and parameters.  "pages" is a sqlite FTS table.

```
INSERT INTO pages (
    docnumsort,
    pagenumsort,
    content
)
SELECT
    @docnumsort,
    @pagenumsort,
    @content
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
        @docnumsort, 
        @pagenumsort,
        @content
    FROM
        pages
    WHERE
        docnumsort = @docnumsort 
        and pagenumsort = @pagenumsort
)
```

```
objCommand = Sourcedb.GetCommand("INSERT INTO pages (docnumsort, pagenumsort, content) SELECT @docnumsort, @pagenumsort, @content WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT @docnumsort, @pagenumsort, @content FROM pages WHERE docnumsort = @docnumsort and pagenumsort = @pagenumsort)")

objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docnumsort", lDNS)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pagenumsort", lPNS)
objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Content", txtToIndex)

objCommand.ExecutNonQuery
```

Tried everything I can think of.

Comment: I barely use SQLite, so maybe there's something I'm not aware of, but it seems odd that you have `SELECT @docnumsort, @pagenumsort, @content` where I would have expected `SELECT docnumsort, pagenumsort, content`. You seem to be using parameters where identifiers are expected.

Comment: (To add to @jmcilhinney) ... and no `FROM` in the `SELECT` before the `WHERE NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: Is it possible sqlite or the provider used only support **positional** parameters, rather than named parameters, meaning you'd have to have 8 separate `AddWithValue()` calls?

Comment: Oh, and I see `@Content` in the C# vs `@content` in the SQL, so I'd double-check this isn't case sensitive.